# AIR IOS - Loading external SWFs that are included in the .ipa

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, mobile, air

I'm trying to load external SWFs that contain embedded assets. Let's assume I have good reasons for doing it that way.

I'm using flash.display.Loader to load the SWF, I'm passing it an instance of flash.system.LoaderContext.
Passing to LoaderContext an applicationDomain of null or new ApplicationDomain() results in error 3747, which from a short google means "Multiple application domains are not supported on this operating system".
Passing to LoaderContext an applicationDomain of ApplicationDomain.currentDomain, results in the app crashing.

In order to embed the assets in the SWF I'm using ActionScript (embed tags).
IOS policy doesn't allow to load external code - I imagine this is the reason for the app crashing.

1) Is there a way to embed assets in the SWF in an automated way without using ActionScript? Perhaps adding them to an FLA's library using a JSFL script would be the way? Any other ideas?

2) Is there a way to load SWFs with different applicationDomains so that class names of different SWFs won't conflict? For instance I might have the class name "someName" in 2 SWFs I'm loading, if I'm passing to LoaderContext the same applicationDomain, there will be a conflict.

Comment: 1) http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2012/11/09/packaging-and-loading-multiple-swfs-in-air-apps-on-ios/

Comment: Have you tried loading the external SWF via URLLoader and using Loader classes loadBytes() method?

Comment: SushiHangover - This article explicitly says in the end that it can't solve my problem, please read the problem and not just the title.
Creative Magic - Would using loadBytes allow me to load external code on IOS? That sound like a breach in their protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was adt's swf stripping, that way I can use code.

Comment: does this also solve the same application domain conflict?